# Android & internal storage memory

Tags: android, memory

If my application makes a file & stores it in the internal memory of the application ie in the path `<internal_storage>/data/data/<package>`, if I uninstall the application will the file that I stored be removed from the location? Also while writing the file if I give any mode(world_readable, world_writable seems to have been deprecated) can any application like file manager see the file that I have created? I have done a lot of research on this topic which has not helped me significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I uninstall the application will the file that I stored be removed from the location?

Yes.

> Also while writing the file if I give any mode(world_readable, world_writable seems to have been deprecated) can any application like file manager see the file that I have created?

- `MODE_PRIVATE`: the default mode, where the created file can only be accessed by the calling application (or all applications sharing the same user ID).
- `MODE_APPEND`: for use with `openFileOutput(String, int)`, if the file already exists then write data to the end of the existing file instead of erasing it.
- `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`: allow all other applications to have read access to the created file.
- `MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE`: allow all other applications to have write access to the created file.

For the last two modes (which are both deprecated), the following should be taken into consideration:

> Creating world-readable files is very dangerous, and likely to cause
>   security holes in applications. It is strongly discouraged; instead,
>   applications should use more formal mechanism for interactions such as
>   `ContentProvider`, `BroadcastReceiver`, and `Service`. There are no
>   guarantees that this access mode will remain on a file, such as when
>   it goes through a backup and restore.

Comment: Is there any way to store data in the internal memory of the tablet which will not get lost with the app uninstall?

Comment: Internal storage, no. You could save it to external storage, knowing it could get deleted/lost anytime. Maybe consider using the network to store and retrieve data from your own web-based services?

Comment: By internal storage I mean the secondary memory of the device, which is huge memory like 2 GB that comes bundled with the device, if I cannot access that, what is the reason that I cannot access it the same way I can access an SD card?